# Datetime problem in VB 2005

Tags: x12

I am using VB2005 and SQL SERVER 2000.

```
PVAR_SQL_STR = "INSERT INTO GLR_US_PERIOD (ORG5_CODE,PERIOD_YEAR,PERIOD_CODE," _
    "PERIOD_NO,FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,INSERT_USER,INSERT_DATE) VALUES " _
    & "('" & PVAR_COMPANY_CODE & "' ,'" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & Serial1.Text & _
    "'," & TextBox2.Text & ", '" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("D") + "' ,'" + _
    DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("D") + "','" & PVAR_USER_CODE & "','" + _
    Now.ToString("F") + "')"
```

Syntax error converting datetime from character string *because of this part only:*

```
Now.ToString("F")
```

Why, I do not know but when I change into

```
Now.ToString("D")
```

it works well but it saves the date only. I want to insert date *and* time.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is not to try to build it all into the SQL statement at all. Use a parameterised query instead, and set the parameter value to `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.UtcNow`) instead.

Parameterised queries are *also* an effective guard against SQL injection attacks. Inserting general data (especially when given by users) into SQL statements directly is a recipe for disaster.

See the [docs for `SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=VS.100).aspx) for more information - or consult just about any decent tutorial or book on ADO.NET.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR MR/JON
i tried it and it working very well